# Getting latest tweet from trending hashtags Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 3 tables (tweets, hashtags, tweets_hashtags)

I currently am using a query that gives me trending hashtags, but I also would like to add a subquery in there to give me the latest tweet containing that trending hashtag. The output actually already gives me a tweet, but it is the first record not the latest.

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS count,
        tweets.date_published,
        tweets.content,
        hashtags.hashtag
FROM
    tweets_hashtags
INNER JOIN hashtags ON tweets_hashtags.hashtag_id = hashtags.id
INNER JOIN tweets ON tweets_hashtags.tweet_id = tweets.id
WHERE tweets.date_published >= 604800
GROUP BY
    tweets_hashtags.hashtag_id
ORDER BY
    count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

What would be the best approach here to get the last tweet record?

Comment: Do you want the latest tweet for each hashtag?

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is currently giving me the tweet with that join, but its the oldest and not the latest associated with the hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you should try this.

```
SELECT
count(*) AS count,
    tweets.date_published,
    tweets.content,
    hashtags.hashtag
FROM
tweets_hashtags
INNER JOIN hashtags ON tweets_hashtags.hashtag_id = hashtags.id
INNER JOIN tweets ON tweets_hashtags.tweet_id = tweets.id
WHERE tweets.date_published >= 604800
GROUP BY
 tweets_hashtags.hashtag_id,tweets.date_published
ORDER BY
count DESC,tweets.date_published DESC
```

Please reply

Comment: Adding the tweets.date_published as a second group-by produced a syntax error. Query does not work.